# Less than operator issue in neo4j

Tags: c#, neo4j, cypher-shell

`>,=` is working but less than operator is not working in cypher neo4j.

What may be the reason ?

Comment: What do you mean with "not working" ? You get an error ? It don't return true when it must be ?

Comment: No, i didn't get any error .<, = operator is working means i got result if value is greater than 41 or equal, but if value is less than 41 then output showing nothing  ,  values are also present

Comment: And so `<` don't show value ? are you sure that you didn't assign value to var. Also, can you show codes ?

Comment: MATCH (n:ProjectField) Where n.value < "41" RETURN n 
output:
"value": "100"
"value": "40214"
"value": "12345"

Comment: welcome to stackoverflow. i recommend [taking the tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour), as well as reading [how to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [what's on topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic).

Comment: And can you edit your first post with that code, and format it ? It will be more useful. Just here I see that you are comparing string and int

Comment: Actually values are saved in string in neo4j database through UI  , And need to find the the less than that values.  Why this happens. i got result for greater than and for Equal using this same query. just not getting for less than

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From your comment
`MATCH (n:ProjectField) Where n.value < "41" RETURN n output: "value": "100" "value": "40214" "value": "12345"` i assume the values you compare are string values (hece the `""`).
In that case cypher uses string comparison and since 1 is smaller than 4 in the first char it think 100 is smaller than 41.

You can try to update the string numbers to integers or compare the integervalues of `n.value` using `toInteger`.